# Array of objects intersection

Tags: javascript

I have two lists of objects and I would like to filter my `array1` without the `file` key that are in the `array2` :

What I did :

```
array1 = array1.filter(function(n) {
    for(var i=0; i < array2.length; i++){
      if(n.file != array2[i].file){
        return n;
      }
    }
});
```

This returns exactly the `array1` whereas if I replace `!=` with `==` it returns the objects I want to get rid of.

I don't understand why.

https://jsfiddle.net/hrzzohnL/1/

So at the end I would like to end with this array :

```
[
    {
     "file": "tttt.csv",
     "media": "tttt"
    }
]
```

Comment: Filter requires you to return true or false values, if you pass it anything else it is (most likely) to be evaluated as 'true', so every item will most likely match. Try adding `if(n.file != array2[i].file){ return true; }` and then `return false` at the end of your function and see if that fixed it.

Comment: @somethinghere Good but the suggestion won't work as it will return as soon as it find an element in array2 that isn't equal to the given element even if the element does appear in array2.

Comment: @DanD. I noticed - this kind of 'compare/uncompare' stuff always gives me a headache. I have added an answer that I put together after some testing in his fiddle, using array methods themselves to make the code look... More predictable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function doesn't do what you want as it doesn't return `false` for values you don't want and `true` for those you want. Consider this:

```
array1 = array1.filter(function(n) {
    for(var i=0; i < array2.length; i++){
      if(n.file == array2[i].file){
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Untested. That returns `false` once it find the element in array2 and otherwise if it wasn't found returns `true`.

Comment: This works. But why replacing the condition by `!=` with the correct `return` (true for first and false at the end) doesnt work ?

Comment: Because the value you returned was not a `boolean`, it was simply the value (`object` in your case). An object will always evaluate to true, as it's a 'truthy' value.

Comment: @DeseaseSparta You have to check that the value is nowhere in the array, your checking would return true if any element is different.

Answer (score 16):

Using `filter` and `some` functions

```js
var array1 = [{ "file": "tttt.csv", "media": "tttt" }, { "file": "bob_bob.csv", "media": "bob_bob" }, { "file": "bob1_bob1.csv", "media": "bob1_bob1" }, ];

var array2 = [{ "title": "bob_bob", "version": "bob", "date": "27/4/2016", "selected": false, "file": "bob_bob.csv", "media": "bob_bob", "exists": true }, { "title": "bob1_bob1", "version": "bob", "date": "27/4/2016", "selected": false, "file": "bob1_bob1.csv", "media": "bob_bob", "exists": true }]

var res = array1.filter(n => !array2.some(n2 => n.file == n2.file));

document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

<sup>*solution uses ES6 arrow function, it may not work in old browsers</sup>

Comment: Might want to mention this is `ES6` and therefor not widely available yet. Fun to use, though.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version that uses some built-in array methods make to this easier for you. It uses `array.some` to return either `true` (when *some* or even one element in the array returns true for the test case) or `false`. Invert that, and you have your filter result. It looks much cleaner!

```js
var array1 = [{"file": "tttt.csv","media": "tttt"},{"file": "bob_bob.csv","media": "bob_bob"},{"file": "bob1_bob1.csv","media": "bob1_bob1"},];

var array2 = [{"title": "bob_bob","version": "bob","date": "27/4/2016","selected": false,"file": "bob_bob.csv","media": "bob_bob","exists": true},{"title": "bob1_bob1","version": "bob","date": "27/4/2016","selected": false,"file": "bob1_bob1.csv","media": "bob_bob","exists": true}]

var result = array1.filter(function(n1) {
  return !(array2.some(function(n2){
   return n1.file === n2.file;
  }))
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a temporary object as reference if the file is in the other array.

```js
var array1 = [{ "file": "tttt.csv", "media": "tttt" }, { "file": "bob_bob.csv", "media": "bob_bob" }, { "file": "bob1_bob1.csv", "media": "bob1_bob1" }],
    array2 = [{ "title": "bob_bob", "version": "bob", "date": "27/4/2016", "selected": false, "file": "bob_bob.csv", "media": "bob_bob", "exists": true }, { "title": "bob1_bob1", "version": "bob", "date": "27/4/2016", "selected": false, "file": "bob1_bob1.csv", "media": "bob_bob", "exists": true }],
    temp = Object.create(null);

array2.forEach(function (a) {
    temp[a.file] = true;
});

array1 = array1.filter(function (a) {
    return !temp[a.file];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

in this case array intersection with _id

```
arraysOfFilterArrays = [array1, array2,array3,array4];

      beforeReady = arraysOfFilterArrays.reduce((a, b) => a.filter(a => b.some(b => a.id === b.id)));

        console.log(beforeReady);
```