# Array intersection (set-theoretic) with Array.prototype.reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays `[a,b,c,d]` and `[b,d,f,h]`.

I want to get an array back with the common elements `[b,d]`.

I can achieve that with a combination of `filter` and `indexOf`:

```
[a,b,c,d].filter(el => [b,d,f,h].indexOf(el) !== -1)
```

but I was wondering if and how I can do the same with `reduce`.

I admit that, despite looking at many examples, `reduce` still is to me one of the most obscure JS methods, so I'd really appreciate some advice.

Comment: Try to implement `filter` using `reduce`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ES6, a propoosal with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The **`includes()`** method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

On every loop of `aa`, reduce adds the element to the result array if the value is found in the test array `bb`. If not found, the former result is returned.

```js
var aa = ['a','b','c','d'],
    bb = ['b','d','f','h'],
    cc = aa.reduce((r, a) => bb.includes(a) && r.concat(a) || r, []);

console.log(cc);
```

Just a smarter approach with using a single array which contains all arrays.

```js
var aa = ['a','b','c','d'],
    bb = ['b','d','f','h'],
    result = [aa, bb].reduce((a, b) => a.filter(c => b.includes(c)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like that a lot, thanks! Do you know a way of using `reduce` _only_ to achieve the same result?

Comment: you mean without includes or indexof?

Comment: Yes, which is probably down to me not understanding `reduce`.

Comment: Good answer Nina! I didn't know exactly the behaviour of your code, so I did a fiddle to better understand for me your code. Probably it would help someone :-)  https://jsfiddle.net/joherro3/c69vgzL4/2/

Comment: reduce is more used to return a single value (which can be an object, or an array) with some operation. the most used example is the addition of an array and return the sum. here is an array the reusult and it is not good practice to use it this way, because the value is always the same (the array) and not a primitive value as itself.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, right its the short form of if... or better a ternary.

Comment: Gotcha. So if I was interested in good practice, `filter` and `indexOf` (or `includes`) would actually be better? @NinaScholz

Comment: i go for filter and includes (if available). for bigger stuff i would use an object as hashtable an use it as sort of includes, like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36895337/1447675) of me.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce is designed to return a single value from a list of items. So filter makes much more sense here.

A good use for reduce would be to return the total number of common elements. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/c69vgzL4/

```
var a = ['a','b','c','d']
var b = ['b','d','f','h']

var number_of_common = b.reduce(function(prev, next) {
    return prev + (a.indexOf(next) + 1 ? 1 : 0)
}, 0)

$('body').html(number_of_common)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only two arrays but for an intersection of n arrays... Let's invent `Array.prototype.intersect()`

```js
Array.prototype.intersect = function(...a) {
  return [this,...a].reduce((p,c) => p.filter(e => c.includes(e)));
}

var arrs = [[0,2,4,6,8],[4,5,6,7],[4,6]],
     arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.intersect(...arrs)));

// or just do

console.log(JSON.stringify(["a","b","c","d"].intersect(["b","d","f","h"])));
```

Comment: Do you need `JSON.stringfy`?

Comment: @U r s u s Actually no but it shows the arrays and objects horizontally.